# How to marshal variable JSON response in struct

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm consuming an API which has some slightly different response when some validation error occurs.

Success response:

```
{ 
   "_status":"success",
   "_data":{ 
      "id":3901,
      "name":"Customer",
      "age":"30"
   }
}
```

Error response:

```
{ 
   "_status":"error",
   "_message":"Validation error",
   "_data":[ 
      { 
         "_field":"name",
         "_error":"You must inform a name"
      },
      { 
         "_field":"age",
         "_error":"Age must be over 50"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've mapped the error response in the struct below, which works fine on error responses but fails on success responses.

```
type Response struct {
    Status    string                  `json:"_status"`
    Message *string                   `json:"_message"`
    Data     []map[string]interface{} `json:"_data"`
}
```

Is there a way to addapt the struct to work even with success responses?

Comment: `Data interface{}` would do it. The problem is for your success response, `_data` is a JSON array, not a JSON object, and only a JSON object can be unmarshaled into a `map`.

Comment: Use `json.RawMessage` for Data, then after the status is unmarshaled based on its value allocate the correct struct for the Data and unmarshal the raw message into that.

Comment: @mkopriva Can you give me some example on that kind of allocation?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/OoGtjfvTcFM there are variations to that of course and you don't have to do it exactly this way, what works best for you.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Comment: I would like to add on this: Usually, when you get an error response, you should have an according status code attached. So you simply could unmarshal to a struct when you have a status code of 200, and to a different struct on 400+

Answer (score 0):

Use `json.RawMessage` as type for data field of struct.
Based on comment, I created a sample program for your scenario as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    type Response struct {
        Status  string          `json:"_status"`
        Message *string         `json:"_message"`
        Data    json.RawMessage `json:"_data"`
    }
    var res Response

    var err error

    var data1 = []byte(`{ 
   "_status":"success",
   "_data":{ 
      "id":3901,
      "name":"Customer",
      "age":"30"
   }
}`)

    var data2 = []byte(`{ 
   "_status":"error",
   "_message":"Validation error",
   "_data":[ 
      { 
         "_field":"name",
         "_error":"You must inform a name"
      },
      { 
         "_field":"age",
         "_error":"Age must be over 50"
      }
   ]
}`)

    err = json.Unmarshal(data1, &res)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("--------", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", res)

    err = json.Unmarshal(data2, &res)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("--------", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", res)

}
```

Output:

```
{success %!s(*string=<nil>) { 
      "id":3901,
      "name":"Customer",
      "age":"30"
   }}
{error %!s(*string=0xc00009e340) [ 
      { 
         "_field":"name",
         "_error":"You must inform a name"
      },
      { 
         "_field":"age",
         "_error":"Age must be over 50"
      }
   ]}
```